# deduce of argument of type class method (overloads by const qualifier) fails with trailing return type in gcc, but not in clang

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++14, trailing-return-type

Nothing clearer than an old good MCVE:

```
struct X {
  auto get(int) const -> int { return {}; }
  auto get(int) -> int { return {}; }
};

template <class R> auto f(auto (X::*)(int) const -> R) {}
//                        ^~~~                   ~~~~
//                        trailing return type

int main() {
  f(&X::get);
}
```

This fails in g++ (4.9.2 & 5.1.0). However if the old return type is used:

```
template <class R> auto f(R (X::*)(int) const) {}
//                        ^
//                        old return type
```

it works.

On clang (3.5.0) both variants work.

I know that trailing return type changes when the return type is inferred and the scope of it, so I wouldn't be quick to cast it as a gcc bug. So what does the standard says? Which compiler is right?

---

The most significant message in the error I think is

> couldn't deduce template parameter ‘R’`

g++ full message:

```
main2.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main2.cpp:21:12: error: no matching function for call to ‘f(<unresolved overloaded function type>)’
   f(&X::get);
            ^
main2.cpp:18:25: note: candidate: template<class R, class auto:1> auto f(auto:1 (X::*)(int) const)
 template <class R> auto f(auto (X::*)(int) const -> R) {}
                         ^
main2.cpp:18:25: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main2.cpp:21:12: note:   types ‘auto:1 (X::)(int) const’ and ‘int (X::)(int)’ have incompatible cv-qualifiers
   f(&X::get);
            ^
main2.cpp:21:12: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘R’
<builtin>: recipe for target 'main2' failed
make: *** [main2] Error 1
```

Comment: Take a look at this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef780f00000f2634 It seems gcc is misinterpreting the parameter type: It doesn't recognize the trailing return type.

Comment: And if you add `-pedantic`, it will also tell you it's interpreting the `auto` as a Concepts-TS-style abbreviated template notation.

Comment: @dyp I compiled with c++14. Anyway with C++14 and `-pedantic` it gives: `ISO C++ forbids use of 'auto' in parameter declaration [-Wpedantic]`

Comment: ... which points to the same fact you said

Comment: Oops, sorry, that was slightly confusing. Neither me nor the gcc errors talk about the `auto` before `f`, we both talk about the `auto` within the parameter-list of `f`. I should have replaced the `auto f` with `void f` for my C++11 test anyway.

Comment: yes I am also talking about the auto if the type of the parameter

Comment: It's quite an interesting bug: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8f9a0115412f3b20 Maybe it hasn't been noticed yet because it usually only raises a warning, and only in pedantic mode?

Comment: but this works: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e65c68f3deffad83

Comment: it seems that it confuses the gcc parser when the type of an argument starts with `auto`

Comment: I've just built g++ tip-of-trunk (6.0) and tried it, same problem / error message. Can't find any relevant open bug reports, so I'd suggest you file one.

Comment: Reported as https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=69139. Probably has something to do with their abbreviated function templates implementation.

Comment: As T.C. commented, this is a GCC bug, which was reported and fixed for GCC 6.1 so the question can be closed/deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed in the question this is a gcc bug which was beed fixed in version 6

[gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=69139](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=69139)